# Renault master red key icon won't shut off

Tags: service, renault

The car is a Renault master 2011. It got a new injector gasket installed and this key light won't turn off. I thought it's an oil warning and tried to follow some instructions from a forum but there was no "Service due ... km" on the dash... the car works just fine but the light can t be shut off even from a computer via obd...
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the wrench icon? or the exclamation mark icon?

Comment: The wrench icon... it is not my car, my neighbor asked me to help him with it. Turns out it has a very small oil leak which may cause the problem but we are not sure yet.

Comment: I'd suggest you check the owners manual to see what the wrench icon indicates. Are there codes in the ECM? What's going on with the Injection A Controller message?

Comment: @Ben There is an "unknown code" that i goolgled and it turns out it was some sort of an ABS error even though it worked just fine. Nevertheless... the engine is broken now... a poorly made gasket failed and a bolt got loose (that is what i understood), had some play and wrecked the crankshaft, eve though the part was brand new... the mechanic who did the job is no newb to repairing cars... he is currently working on it, and had the engine removed, therefore being able to check and repair other faulty parts.It's a Renault... a lot of mechanics say that stuff like this happens to Renault cars...